# Inserting a picture does not loop without adding the same picture into the same cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the below code to add multiple pics in an excel file, but seem to be struggling around the For Loop for one, so I've tried the Do loop. The problem is that the same picture is added each time to the same cell when in fact, the following pics should be moved to the next range. Would really appreciate your input.

```
Sub ScopePics()

Dim fullpath, server, thefile, thisbook As String
Dim picname As String
Dim pic_location As String
Dim picnum As Integer
Dim picadd As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

File_name = Sheet2.Cells(3, 10)
pic_location = Sheet2.Cells(622, 10)
picname = Sheet2.Cells(623, 10)
pastePic = Sheet2.Cells(626, 10)
maxP = Sheet2.Cells(627, 10)
Scopebook = Sheet2.Cells(609, 10)
picnum = Sheet2.Cells(624, 10)
picadd = Sheet2.Cells(625, 10)

Do
Workbooks(Scopebook).Activate
Sheets("Scope of Work").Select

Range(pastePic).Select

'For x = 1 To maxP Step 1
 'picadd = picnum + 1

    Dim FS
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        If FS.FileExists(pic_location) Then

        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic_location).Select

        With Selection

            .Left = Range(pastePic).Left + 5
            .Top = Range(pastePic).Top + 5

            .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .ShapeRange.Height = 35#
            .ShapeRange.Width = 45#

        End With

        ActiveSheet.Pictures(pic_location).Refresh 'Tried this to try to refresh but its not working. 

    End If
Windows(File_name).Activate

Sheets("Control").Select
Cells(624, 10).Value = Cells(624, 10).Value + 1
Calculate
Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#) 'Tried this to see if the delay would help but still not working. 
Calculate
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic_location).Refresh

Workbooks(Scopebook).Activate
Loop Until picnum = picadd

ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Inside the loop you need to update the variables so for each iteration the variables change to specify the new picture and new location. Your variables are all set only once before the loop.

Comment: As thril says, you are defining the paste location `pic_location` outside your loop.  Make it so that is defined inside your loop with a counter.

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you both for your contribution to this matter. I'm just not certain I understand how to implement the suggestion. Would it be much trouble asking you to post an example of this please?

Comment: In addition to the above, I've tried to incorporate the above suggestions but now get a duplicate declaration in current scope error. Any suggestions around this?

Comment: meaning you used `dim`twice for the same variable. declare variables before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Patrick. The problem is that I don't have much experience with VB so trying to initiate these suggestions generally don't work out because I just can't seem to get it to run smoothly.

Comment: So after spending my Sunday night toying with the code, I've finally got this thing to work. Slightly different from the previous code, but here's what I've done.

Comment: Ok, seems I can't add the code due to limited typing space.